# .htaccess skip apple-app-site-association but filter other

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, skip, apple-app-site-association

I have a rule for changing the extension

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)/?$ item.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

All fine But this rule also filter apple-app-site-association

Need skip apple-app-site-association but filter other

I tried add code below but to no avail

```
RewriteRule ^apple([a-z]+)$ $1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule apple-app-site-association$ $1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apple([a-z]+)$ $1 [NC,L,S=2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)/?$ item.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The condition above makes sure you don't rewrite your existing files and folders.